# R ggplot: How to align points with dodged bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, position-dodge

I'd like to know how to align geom_point points with the geom_bar dodged bars positions.

The bars are dodged according to the Year parameter but the points all plot in the middle of the dodged bars regardless of their Year parameter.

[image]

Reproducible code:

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(Response = rep(paste0("Response",1:4),2),
                  Proportion = round(runif(8),2),
                  Year = c(rep(2017,4),rep(2018,4)))
industries <- data.frame(Response = rep(paste0("Response",1:4),6),
                         Proportion = round(runif(24),2),
                         Year = rep(c(rep(2017,4),rep(2018,4)),3),
                         Cat = rep(paste0("Cat",1:3),c(rep(8,3))))
ggplot(dat, aes(Response, Proportion, label = paste0(Proportion*100,"%"), fill = factor(Year))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge" ) + 
  geom_point(data = industries, aes(Response, Proportion, fill = factor(Year), col= Cat), size = 3) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 1), angle = 90)
```

Comment: Add `position = position_dodge(width = 1)` to your `geom_point`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need `group = factor(Year)` in `aes()`, then `position = position_dodge(1)` (as suggested by @Tung). Also repeating `x, y` in `aes()` for `geom_point()` is superfluous:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(Response, Proportion, label = paste0(Proportion*100,"%"), 
                fill = factor(Year))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge" ) + 
  geom_point(data = industries, aes(col= Cat, group = factor(Year)), size = 3,
             position = position_dodge(1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 1), angle = 90)
```

[image]