# geom points are not placed on the boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point, position-dodge

I don't know how to align the dots to each belong to it is box plot.
Why they are appearing like that?

[image]

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650423/r-ggplot-how-to-align-points-with-dodged-bars), but it is answering the dodging part which is not part of my code

here is my code

```
library(phyloseq)
library(ggplot2)

plot_richness(ps.prev.intesParts.f, x = "part", measures = "Shannon", 
              color = "Samples") +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle = 90),
        legend.title = element_blank())) +
  labs(x = "Intestinal Parts", y = "Shannon Index")
```

Could you please advise?

Comment: Your problem is that dodging isn't part of your code. The way the boxplots are next to each other even though they share the same x-values is called "dodging". You need to dodge the points in the same was as the boxplots are dodged automatically. The answer at your link looks like a very good start, if not a full solution.

Comment: If you can share some reproducible data using `dput`, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you need to specify dodging. However, dodging needs to be set in the underlying `geom_point(...)` of the `plot_richness` function itself. Unfortunately, phyloseq offers no such option. This means you'll need to calculate the alpha diversity measures yourself and generate your own plot. Luckily this only requires a few extra lines of code. Here's an example using phyloseq's `GlobalPatterns`.

```r
require("phyloseq")
require("dplyr")
require("ggplot2")

# Load data
data("GlobalPatterns")

# Calculate alpha indices
a_div <- estimate_richness(GlobalPatterns, measures = "Shannon")
a_div$SampleID <- row.names(a_div)

# Add sample_data from physeq object
a_div <- left_join(a_div, 
                   sample_data(GlobalPatterns), 
                   by = c("SampleID" = "X.SampleID"))

# GlobalPatterns only has grouping by SampleType. 
# Generate an extra group by duplicating all rows
a_div <- rbind(a_div, a_div)
a_div$Samples <- rep(x = c("MMV", "VMV"), 
                     each = nrow(a_div)/2)

# Plot
ggplot(a_div,
       aes(x = SampleType,
           y = Shannon,
           colour = Samples)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle = 90,
                                          hjust = 1,
                                          vjust = 0.5),
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>